# Open and then kill child process from bash

Tags: bash, parent-child, kill

What's the best way of executing a command and then killing it after some time? Here's what I have; it does the job, but I get `amp: command not found` and although I'm not sure why the amp is there in the first place, I know that the killing doesn't work without it.

```
feh "$output""$ext" &amp;
echo $!
sleep 1
kill -s 9 $!
exit 1
```

The thing is that I don't know the PID of the process I'm executing. Could I assign one upon execution?

Comment: You probably got to look at some code that was converted for display as HTML; the `&amp;` would display as `&` in HTML.

Comment: Why put `$!` into a variable? Does this have any advantage?

Comment: If you put `$!` into a variable, you won't lose the value if you run something else in the background.

Comment: Unless you know the consequences, you should avoid `kill -9`. See http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#kill

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[GNU timeout](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html), part of recent versions of coreutils, does exactly what you want.

```
timeout 1 feh "$output""$ext"
```

runs `feh` for one second and then kills it, if it hasn't already ended.

The rest of this comment concerns your current recipe:

The recipe you're currently using puts `feh` into the background using the `&`. The `amp;` after it is a mistake, likely from some overzealous HTML encoder (`&amp;` is how you spell `&` in HTML).

Every process is assigned a PID by the kernel when launched. `$!` is the shell variable for the pid of the most recently backgrounded process.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by recent?

Comment: `timeout`'s first stable release was, as far as I can tell, in coreutils 7.1, which came out in 2009.

Comment: Elegant and intuitive! very nice answer. +1 for me.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want "&amp;" you just want "&". The ampersand tells bash to run the process in the background.

The $! is set to the pid of the background process, so otherwise your sample should do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
feh "$output""$ext" &
FEHPID=$!
sleep 1
kill -s 9 $FEHPID
exit 1
```

Comment: This is the most general solution, because you can do other stuff on your main script, which you can't do in daxelrod's solution. I just wish it didn't say `kill -9` :-)